# Print any number of triangles of a given size - Output Prints Extra Trailing White Spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

Print any number of triangles of a given size.

The program will take the triangle height and number of triangle rows from standard input.

The height and number of rows should both be in the range [1, 20].

If the height is invalid or missing, print Invalid height. and quit.

If the number of rows is invalid or missing, print Invalid number of rows. and quit.

There should be no trailing whitespace after each line of output.

My program is almost correct except trailing whitespaces, but I don't know how to remove these trailing spaces.

```
import sys
size = input('Enter height: ')
if (not str(size).isdigit()) or int(size) >20 or int(size)<1:
    print()
    print('Invalid height.')
    exit()
level = input('Enter number of rows: ')
if (not str(level).isdigit()) or int(level) >20 or int(level)<1:
    print()
    print('Invalid number of rows.')
    exit()
print()
height=int(size)
row=int(level)
def solve(height, row):
    for i in range(0, row):
        for k in range(0, height):
            for j in range(0, (row - i) * height - k-1):
                print(" ",end='')
            if (k != height - 1):
                for j in range(0, i+1):
                    print("/",end='')
                    for l in range(0, k * 2):
                        print(" ",end='')
                    print("\\",end='')
                    for l in range(0, (height - k - 1) * 2):
                        print(" ",end='')
            else:
                for j in range(0, i + 1):
                    print("/",end='')
                    for l in range(0, (height - 1) * 2):
                        print("_",end='')
                    print("\\",end='')
            print("\n",end='')
solve(height, row)
```

Actual result 1(almost correct apart from trailing white spaces):
[image]

Actual result 2(almost coorrect apart from trailing white spaces):
[image]
Actual result 3(almost coorrect apart from trailing white spaces):
[image]
Actual result 4(almost coorrect apart from trailing white spaces):
[image]

Comment: Try using the `.strip()` to remove trailing whitespaces. Eg. `yourstring.strip()`

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup .strip() will also remove any leading whitespaces. A possible way that's kinda dirty is to split your line at "\" using `line.split("\\")` and then join everything except for the last item: `"\\".join(line.split("\\")[:-1]) + "\\"`

Comment: Ah, yes I overlooked that *simple fact. :)

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup But some white spaces are needed to print, just need to remove whitespaces outside the triangle, I heard someone said the formula that inside the range() are not correct,do you know how to modify the formula inside the 'range()' to let the function not print superfluous whitespaces?

Comment: Yeah it's range(1,21) for [1,20] (as an example)

Comment: @TimWoocker I haven't use that way before, can you help me modify it (and comment)to let it not print superfluous whitespaces?

Comment: So, for nums in the `range [x,y]`, use `range(x,y+1)`

Comment: Which software are you using to compile your program?

Comment: @Justin a software from my university, this is a exercise from school

Comment: @Eric - Oh, because when I run it on Spyder I don't get any trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @Eric - What is the name of the software?

Comment: @Justin edstem.org, our university use it

Comment: @Justin python is an interpreted language. That means you can not compile your code (in theory you can but it's different than what you are talking about). Spyder is just a development environment which does not affect how the code is executed. Only the python interpreter can change python's behaviour. In this question, however, the whitespace is caused by a logical mistake which should occur on any interpreter. So you probably just did not notice the trailing white space: It is there 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `if j!=i` below `print("\\", end='')`, and it should work.
This will check if you just printed the last `\` of the line and skip printing the following spaces.

```
print("\\", end='')
if j!=i:
    for l in range(0, (height - k - 1) * 2):
        print(" ", end='')
```